# How parse json with inside HTML tag in java?

Tags: java, html, json, xml

I create a JSON String from an XML file. Now in my JSON, there is some HTML tag that makes it invalid. I used common.lang3 for encoding HTML but Still, it has a problem. I don't want to remove or replace HTML tag.

```
    JSONArray newsJSONArray = new JSONArray();
    int start = 0;
    int end = 5;
    List<NewsModel> newsList = NewsDAO.get(start, end);

    for (NewsModel newsModel : newsList) {
        JSONObject newsJSONObj = new JSONObject();

        String trueContent = newsModel.getContent();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db;
        Document doc;
        try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(trueContent)));
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String output = (String) xpath.compile("root/static-content")
                    .evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);

            String content = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(output);
            newsJSONObj.put("title", newsModel.getTitle());
            newsJSONObj.put("displayDate", newsModel.getDisplayDate());
            newsJSONObj.put("content", content);
            newsJSONArray.add(newsJSONObj);

        }
```

My JSON output is this :

```
   "content":" &lt;p&gt;&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot;   
              src=&quot;data:image\/png;base64,
              iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA7YAAAVx
```

Comment: A) what is the problem with the output? B) why are are you calling this escapeHtml3 method when you can just use the output variable in newsJSONObj directly?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt it is invalid JSON. I use escaphtml3 for encoding HTML but it is useless

Comment: You have to JSON (or Javascript) escape your text, not HTML. So use ``StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(output)``.

Comment: @Sascha there isn't "escapeJson" method

Comment: Ah, the method was added in version 3.2. Maybe you can update the lib?

Comment: It's irrelevant that it's invalid json. It's the json libraries responsibility to encode it, not yours. Did you try not escaping?